# Command to launch the ALT+F2 window?

Tags: gnome-panel

I removed all of my gnome-panel's in favor of the Avant Window Manager for a number of reasons, and would really like to not have to have a gnome-panel still just being hidden.

Is there a command to launch the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> window without having a gnome-panel active? I'd like to add an icon to my dock that launches that window, or a window that let's me run a command like that one.

Comment: Do you mean Avant Window *Navigator?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the Alt+F2 window is a dialog within gnome-panel, so you can't really launch it standalone.

I highly suggest using gnome-do instead though.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

Comment: Runs a lot better on my netbook than I expected it would. I'm oddly lagging less with AWM and Gnome-Do than I was without them. >.>

Comment: I've been using AWN plus GNOME Do for several months now — works great.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement Ken's great answer, I would add that the openbox window manager includes the `gnome-panel-control` program that allows you to call up the GNOME Run Dialog. You could install openbox without using the window manager and use the following command:

```
gnome-panel-control --run-dialog
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to gnome-do is kupfer - http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kupfer

Answer (score 0):

According to here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9813331&postcount=2 there are a number of simple run dialogue programs: gmrun, Alawalk, Bashrun and Lauf. Lauf is apparently good.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a launcher, you can install guake. Its a drop-down terminal, much like the consoles in FPS games where you entered cheat codes.